Apache serving raw text PHP files after update to 2.4.60
Weird issue post a version bump for Apache 2.4.59 -> 2.4.60
I've been compiling Apache for my own servers for decades now, this is not a ports/pkg/apt/whatever issue.
On a CentOS (8) server (but that's almost certainly irrelevant), the only one I've tried so far, ever since I bumped apache to 2.4.60, it's been serving raw files (which firefox then offers to save as a file) instead of rendering PHP, IF the file is from a redirect etc.  ie: If I tell Firefox to get https://servername/ (which would normally pick up index.php and parse it as usual) I get firefox offering to save the raw PHP file index.php - so it's "finding" it but not running it.
If on the other hand, I tell it explicitly to grab index.php, eg https://servername/index.php
it works as normal, until it then tries to grab some other page that isn't explicitly using the filename.php to get to it anyway. This tells me something's gone odd in 2.4.60's rewriting/index parsing.
My PHP files are sitting on a server that uses a symlink to map their root directory to a version stamp (it's a moodle, I use this : /dir/www -> /dir/mooodle-version.number) which has worked for many, many years and makes version swaps easy. I haven't tried removing this and seeing if that fixes it, but it's next on the list.
Apache error log shows nothing weird:
[Tue Jul 02 09:33:13.415549 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1112:tid 1112] AH00489: Apache/2.4.60 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.2.20 configured -- resuming normal operations

Apache httpd.conf relevant section:
LoadModule php_module         modules/libphp.so
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

Anyone? Bueller? I'm kinda stumped. I'd like to bump all my Apaches ASAP, but until this works, not an option!

update - removing the symlink didn't fix it.

Apache 24.60 fixes several vulnerabilities, including CVE-2024-38476 .
Unfortunately, this release also brings some breaking changes with it:

Note: Some legacy uses of the 'AddType' directive to connect a request to a handler must be ported to 'SetHandler' after this fix.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what they mean with "legacy uses". According to the Docs, AddType still is completely valid and not considered deprecated..

There's a thread on the Apache httpd user mailing list about it, they mention that the CHANGENOTES will be updated to suit. A bit late after it goes out!  But at least it's now known and search engines can find it.

It turns out this is a, well, I'd call it a bug ... a change in 2.4.60 WRT handlers
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

change to
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

And that fixes it.
Nice one, Apache ... Hrm. Who doesn't love undocumented changes?!
